# WordPress pages break with custom permalink settings (theme directory not output)

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

We have a site under development which works fine locally, however when uploaded to our server using the permalink settings %postname% the correct URLs are rendered in the menu but in all pages other than home no WP theme URL is output

for example: http://distinctivepeople.co.uk/wp/ works fine 
http://distinctivepeople.co.uk/wp/who-we-are/  does not output the theme directory so renders unstyled HTML

This works fine under default settings p?=123 etc but we need proper URLs.

This is hosted with 123-reg who don't believe there is a server issue - previously similar has happened if .htaccess is not being read by the server but I'm told this is not the case.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How have you included your stylesheet link?

Comment: It's a css problem, look at your source code, it's look like the theme path wasn't set.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/css/dp.css" media="all" />

Comment: it is set. as above, see the homepage - works fine, also works on these pages under default permalink settings but not for custom settings

Comment: it's getting the index file from the root instead of any files from the theme directory when these permalink settings are set

Comment: I was trying to answer but your site's disappeared.  Before it did there seemed to be a problem with a slash missing from the stylesheet URI and also a problem with the mime type of the stylesheet file that my browser complained about.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook sorry I tried moving the site to the root to see if that fixed but no joy.

Comment: To add : http://distinctivepeople.co.uk/wp/ renders correctly 

Trying to navigate to another page when permalinks are set to %postname% is getting the index file from the root (current holding page) - nothing to do with the WP install in /wp/

Comment: OK - so the page I see for the sub URL is actually an HTML file at the root?  Can I see your .htaccess?

Comment: if you correctly set you child theme (get_stylesheet_uri instead of get_template) and set the options settings, you need to investigate with your dns and redirection settings from your host.

Comment: That's correct @AndyMacaulay-Brook - htaccess :

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Not using a child theme - referencing the scc and other files via:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/css/dp.css" media="all" />

Comment: That's brought it too light - I removed the upper declarations in the htaccess file and happy days - thank you @AndyMacaulay-Brook !!

Comment: No problem.  Write it up as an answer and accept it yourself!  I'll delete my half answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved with the help of @AndyMacaulay-Brook

The htaccess had some incorrect (non-wp declarations) which when removed solved the issue:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /wp/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Removing everything outside of the WP declarations fixed the issue